# Movement of centre of mass in absence of any external force during Thermal Expansion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

Recently wile solving questions on Thermal Expansion I encountered two types of questions

Type 1: A rod with one half of mass 'm' and the other of mass '2m' is kept on a horizontal smooth surface, it is heated and it expands longitudinally.

In this question centre of mass of system(the whole rod) remains same at the initial position, before and after expansion

Type 2: A uniform rod of mass m is kept on a rough inclined plane and it is heated. The rod expands and the centre of mass moves. Even though the net force on the body is zero.
[image]
I'm not able to analyze that why the centre of mass moves in second case but it doesn't move in the first.

Comment: Is the system just the rod, or the combined rod and plane?  The body seems to suggest it is just the rod.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas That looks like an answer.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Ok, moved to an answer, by request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a rod is resting on an inclined plane, then there must be sufficient friction for it not to slide entirely.   But if the rod changes shape, then the friction on the plane must have been overcome on at least some portions of the interface where the rod is touching.

So you have a partially unknown amount of friction from the ramp applying forces to the rod.   I don't think "absence of any external force" would apply.

Comment: But still the frictional force balances the net effective weight acting along the inclined plane. Therefore, net force is zero , if you consider the whole rod

Comment: Or i should say, *net* frictional force balances the weight acting along the inclined plane

Comment: If the rod has moved, then that's not true.   You have no information about how the friction is acting except the result on the rod.   You're not given any information about how it acts.   *Because* the rod moves, you know the net force on the rod is not zero at all times.

Comment: Umm, it was a numerical problem, so i guess i solved it, there was this one point (say, P) above l/2 which was fixed . That means above P the frictional force was acting in downward direction and below P frictional force was acting in upward direction.

Comment: If one point remains fixed , i guess the rod is actually not displacing, it's just some points are displacing from their position. Also, they are moving very slowly so we can assume the acceleration to be 0.

Comment: Very slowly and "very close to zero" are not zero.   There is at least some time when the net force on the rod is not zero.   This is due to friction forces not being constant.  It is not true that there is an "absence of external force".

Comment: okay i think i get it, when the object was initially at rest, there was some different value of static friction but when it starts moving, kinetic friction acts on it (with different value, right? 

Also, can you pls confirm that it would be symmetric expansion or asymmetric expansion. I mean after expansion would the mass per unit length constant along the whole rod?

Comment: That's unstated in your problem.  I would assume symmetric expansion unless something in the problem suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second case stress forces must overcome gravity expanding up the hill, while expansion down the hill is accelerated by gravity, hence com moves down the hill.

Comment: So will there be asymmetric expansion?

Comment: Exactly, friction force and gravity cancels each other down the hill, while up the hill it amplifies each other, so this makes expansion more easier down the hill and hence asymmetric.